# What proportion of revolutions that overthrew tyrannical regimes made things as bad or worse?

Tags: revolution, civil-war, rebellion

I realize that a phrase like "as bad or worse" is subjective. By what metric do we decide if a new regime is "better" or "worse" than an old one?

However, I want to know if this is a known area of research in historical revolutions. History seems to be full of cases where a horrible government that oppresses its people eventually gets overthrown by well-meaning rebels, but because those rebels are either incompetent, more malicious than their supporters thought, or simply very naive about the difficulty of running a state effectively, their replacement regime ends up being worse. Judging from what I have heard, my intuition is that regime-changing revolutions almost never get replaced with better regimes. But, of course, my intuition is very vulnerable to the availability heuristic. It would be nice if someone has tried to evaluate this objectively.

While I recognize the subjectivity of how "good" a state is, I think you can pick some metrics (such as homicide rate, rate of death from starvation, overall state wealth, etc) to judge what happened to a state post-revolution.

What proportion of regime-changing revolutions turned out better/worse than the regime it overthrew, by any metric? Additionally, is this an open question being researched by quantitative historians? If so, links to the most salient publications on the topic would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Close to 98%. The only example I can find where what you describe did *not* happen is 1990 in central europe.

Comment: My sense is that this hasn't really been looked at systematically. It would be tough to prove causality and to define the appropriate time horizon. [Here](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=oT86uvC8KBEC&oi=fnd&pg=PA41) is a review of comparative studies of revolutions more generally. They seem to focus on the question of immediate success or failure vs. well-being of the population.

Comment: Maybe you can define the metric, and later on open other questions with other metrics, otherwise this question will be too broad. Besides, revolutions where population claims for independence instead of change of goverment not always end bad (India independence, USA independence), unless there is a division among independentist movements, because often, civil war follows an independence/overthrow.

Comment: Different metrics would give diametrically opposed answers.  Almost all revolutions give rise to a counterrevolution, which is pretty solid evidence that people are willing to put their lives on the line for both opinions. Were the Articles of Confederation better than Colonial status?  If so, why did we have to over throw them for teh Constitution?  How many different times did the French revolution play out?  You could make a strong argument that the _reason_ for revolution is that the maintenance of the status quo simply requires too much effort....

Comment: @Bregalad: Have you considered the US or Revolutionary France? The consequences of the latter two are still in full swing today by some arguments...

Comment: "bad or worse" for who?  All conflicts have winners and losers.

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy I'm biased because I live 50km close to the border of France and this country is a great rival of mine, but IMO the French Revolution has catastrophic consequences up to todays.... In that country nobody respects authority of any kind and this has bad consequences for public order, economy, etc... Also neededless to say but the short and medium-term consequences of French revolution were abyssal.

Comment: @Bregalad: "In that country nobody respects authority of any kind" is factually incorrect. The French crave authority to a point where two Napoleons took over, and one of the goals of the subsequent constitutions was to avoid that the masses be able to elect a new dictator.

Comment: @Denis de Bernardy I think you must adopt a somewhat less sweeping point of view.  If you judge the American and French revolution unreviewable because they are as still ongoing -- and I understand your point, here -- then you can essentially never make any kind of judgment in human affairs.  (Besides, history is chaotic in the technical sense and you can *never* validly compare what actually happened to what might have happened because we can never know the latter with any useful accuracy.)

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace I re-edited the question with my original title, but in the last paragraph I emphasized that that's the specific question I want answered. But I added a request for relevant publications if there are any. (I know that asking for research on a question is *technically* a different question than the question itself, but I don't think that warrants a separate post on a stack exchange.)

Comment: Interesting question, but ultimately opinion based unless you can quantify "better" - I suspect that Wallace's first law may be for any value of "better" there will be humans who will violently argue for and against.

Comment: @MarkOlson: Respectfully disagree. My view merely is that history takes a very long time to play out. To me, for instance, French-Prussia rivalry (and subsequent wars, including WW2 and its consequences) has its roots in the massacres in the Palatinate during Louis XIV's reign. Before that there basically wasn't any animosity between the French and Germans. It's been a slow motion train wreck of sorts since, until the EU came about.

Comment: @Denis de Bernardy Sure it is, but what does that matter to me?  It's possible that some post-singularity being contemplating the Cosmic All will conclude that Nazism was a good thing. That possibility does not stop me -- and I'll bet it doesn't stop you -- from saying that it was a terrible thing and being glad that our fathers risked their lives to stop it.  I don't think it's useful to take such a long view.

Comment: @Bregalad Did you mean to respond to me?  I didn't say anything about India.

Comment: @MarkOlson: It does not indeed. Unless, like me, you find it useful to take the long view. With respect to the nazis, for instance, I would point to the lot of 19th century Aryan-/Atlantis-/Mysticism-/conspiracy theorists that, incidentally, gave us the Protocols of the Elders of Zion and Hitler among other sorry outcomes, and many pogroms before that. But more to the point, you can still see some of their arguments being put forward in modern-day white nationalists in the US. (And that, btw, is f'ing scary, seeing how WW2 was deadly already, and how strong the US military is.)

Comment: @StevenBurnap Sorry I wanted to respond to santiago

Comment: @Santiago  India independance was a catastrophe and ended in the largest ethnic cleansing of human history. How can you pretend "it didn't end bad" ?!?